# UITableViewRowAction works in simulator but not on device?

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios-simulator, uitableviewrowaction

I have a table view with `UITableViewRowAction` on the cells so I can swipe a cell to reveal an action.  It works perfectly on the simulator but not on device.  Any ideas why?

```
var deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            self.foodTableView.dataSource?.tableView?(
                self.foodTableView,
                commitEditingStyle: .Delete,
                forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath

            )

        return [deleteButton]
    }
```